# Why "Questions that may already have your answer" doesn't populate the right set of similar questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I posted this [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/294066/name-of-an-accessory-put-on-horses-that-helps-them-avoid-distraction) after searching a few times(through Google and within ELU Search).

Turns out , it had already been asked and answered before [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/254998/looking-for-the-word-which-covers-the-eye-lid-of-the-horses-and-led-the-horse-to) and consequently, my question was marked as duplicate.

My disappointment lies in the fact that even the **Questions that may already have your answer** dynamic list did not match my question to the already existing one. I guess it matches tags and few words from the title and body to populate the list.

- Do I need to configure anything additionally to get the most appropriate matches?
- What are the best practices to avoid duplicates, as someone who wants to ask?

I can only search a few times but I need some support from the SE's search algorithms to come up with the questions that already exists. It will save everyone's time I believe.

Comment: I have similarly noted the difficulty in the SO search (either the search box or the auto search when typing a question title). And google's seems to do much better (once the question is google-indexed). Search engine behavior needs a lot of tweaking to do well.

Comment: When I searched the keywords "horse distraction", I found the duplicate question. How did you search? You can try with fewer but most relevant keywords. However, search mechanism is not perfect and you can google also like "[site:english.stackexchange.com horse eyes](https://www.google.ca/#q=site:english.stackexchange.com+horse+eyes)".

Comment: One only has to view "related" questions on EL&U (not so much meta) to see how totally  *unrelated* they are to the OP's question. EL&U's search tool is quite bad, but I'm sure searching *horses*, *eyes*, and *straight* in the search box  would have shown up the older question.

Comment: I too found the duplicate for OP's question straight away using a Google "site-specific" search. But that's because I already knew the answer, so I just searched for *blinkers* and there it was at the top of the results returned. Doubtless it would have been the same if I'd happened to search for *blinders* using Google, but the "original" is the third result returned by the SO site search facility anyway, and apparently OP did already know this term (and was looking for alternatives). I don't really see a problem here.

Comment: Related: *[A new search engine for Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100)* at MSE.